# Is it normal for drip hose to tear when pulled from compression fitting?

Tags: drip-system, hoses

I have an older drip/soaker hose setup that I'm attempting to patch.  I've had leak troubles which means I have pulled the hoses from the compression fittings several times while attempting to fix it.  The old hose deals with this just fine but the new stuff tears every time. The older hose is also smoother, while the new one has a pebbled surface and seems like it might be made of recycled bits of something else. Is this normal with newer product or did I get a poor quality hose?

Answer (score 3):

I think you must have got a cheap hose. In my experience, you should be able to pull them apart without trouble. It sounds like you got a hose molded from shredded rubber or something, which explains wht they are ripping. That stuff isn't very strong. When looking for a drip hose, I tend to get the most expensive hose in the style I like. Quality does differ a lot.